# What luminosity value is considered as "light"?

Tags: java, image, colors, rgb

I have to decide whether image is light or dark, and I have equation like this:

```
double luminosity = ((r * 0.2126) + (g * 0.7152) + (b * 0.0722)) / 255
```

Using this equation, what pixel value is considered as 'light'?

Are there any other popular / best practices in deciding if image is light / dark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your range of values is from when r, g, b equal 0 (pixel is black) and to when r, g, b all equal 255 (pixel is white)- plugging that in will give us a luminosity range of **[0, 1]**.

One way would be to simply say - if luminosity value is below 0.5, this is "dark pixel", if luminosity is larger than 0.5 - that is "light pixel".

If inside the image we have a majority of dark pixels, the image is dark. If majority of pixels in image are light, image is light. Alternatively, get luminosity value for each pixel in the image and take the average - and then use the average luminosity to determine if image is light or dark.

Some values for individual pixel examples:

```
rgb(245, 100, 3) = luminosity 0.49 - darker
```

[image]

```
rgb(245, 120, 3) = luminosity 0.54 - lighter
```

[image]

```
rgb(100, 140, 3) = luminosity 0.48 - darker
```

[image]

```
rgb(100, 200, 3) = luminosity 0.64 - lighter
```

[image]

Comment: Should I use median for that, or for example 
[Summed Area table](https://computersciencesource.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/computer-vision-the-integral-image/) or some kind of histogram?

Comment: @kkot it can be as simple as just having a count of "dark pixels" and "light pixels" and comparing the amount of each, or you can take average for all pixels. How complex you make it is up to you :)

Comment: I agree with the answer. In fact middle grey is 0.5 [Note: we are assuming R,G,B gamma corrected]. Photo cameras expose so that image [or the spot used for exposition] has half grey brightness.

Comment: To average all pixels is easy. Use 3 long. Add all red, add blue, add all green. Then average, then calculate luminosity.